# Выбор не повторяющихся элементов из массива?

Tags: javascript

Я когда-то написал функцию выбора не повторяющихся элементов, но щас не могу найти исходник.
Вообщем нашел готовую функцию на просторах интернета, но есть проблема. 
Сейчас я использую это:

```
function shuffle1(array) {
    let counter = array.length;
    while (counter > 0) {
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        counter--;
        let temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

function randomArray(arr, len) {
    let cachearr = []
    cachearr = shuffle1(arr);
    cachearr.length = len;
    shuffle1(arr);
    return cachearr;
}
```

Во первых: у меня сейчас массив из 10 элементов, я вывожу 8 функцией randomArray, но остальные 2 не выводятся вообще, только эти 8 элементов меняются местами и все. Я же сделал локальный массив внутри этой функции, собственно в чем проблема ?

Comment: как вызываешь?.

Comment: может len неправильный? console.log(randomArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 10)); такой код работает

Comment: _"Я же сделал локальный массив внутри этой функции_" - вы **не** сделали копию массива: `length` меняется у исходного массива (который `arr` в `randomArray`, он же `array` в `shuffle1`, и он же `cachearr` со строки `cachearr = shuffle1(arr)`).

Comment: И зачем дважды перемешивать массив?

Comment: @Regent тогда как нужно сделать чтоб length не влиял на исходный массив, либо есть какой то другой способ вывода нужного количества ?

Comment: @Gigabait сделайте `cachearr` действительно копией массива, после чего спокойно меняйте у него длину, не портя при этом исходный массив. Копию можно сделать, например, так: `let arrayCopy = array.slice()` или так: `let arrayCopy = [...array];`. С помощью метода `slice`, кстати, можно сразу взять копию массива нужной длины и не менять `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для итерации для массивов лучше всего использовать функции высшего порядка: `map()`, `every()`, `filter()`, `find()`, `findIndex()`, `reduce()`, `some()`.

### Вывод массива с уникальными значениями через `filter`

```js
let yourArray = [1, , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11];

uniqueArray = yourArray.filter((elem, index, array) => array.indexOf(elem) == index);

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

### Перемешивание массива [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

```js
let yourArray = [1, , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11];

uniqueArray = yourArray.filter(
  (elem, index, array) => array.indexOf(elem) == index
);

function shuffle(a) {
  let j, x, i;
  for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    x = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(shuffle(uniqueArray));
```

Если есть вопросы по ответу, обращайтесь.

### Финальная версия

```js
let yourArray = [1, , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11];

function crazyArray(inputArray, outputLength) {
  function shuffle(a) {
    let j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      x = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
  }

  let result = inputArray.filter(
    (elem, index, array) => array.indexOf(elem) == index
  );

  return shuffle(result).slice(0, outputLength);
}

console.log(crazyArray(yourArray, 5));
```

Comment: Как по мне, под "выбор не повторяющихся элементов из массива" подразумевается, что один и тот же элемент массив не должен браться дважды. Уникальность элементов в массиве при этом не требуется. Собственно, и в коде автора массив никак не фильтруется.

Comment: По самому коду: почему `uniqueArray` не объявлен с помощью `let`, и намеренно ли вы в одних местах используете `let`, а в других - `var`? Насколько хорошо делать массив уникальным за `O(n^2)` - это уже отдельный разговор.

Comment: За перемешивание массива спасибо, но вопрос был в другом. У меня сейчас проблема в том что при выводе массива через функцию randomArray   изменяется его дина через length, и оставшиеся элементы не выводятся. Как вы можете предложить решить эту проблему ?

Comment: @Gigabait сначала ты хочешь удалить дубликаты в массиве, потом перемешать и потом обрезать `n` первых элементов?

Comment: @NikitaSmith нет, я хотел вывести перемешанный массив с не повторяющимися элементами и определенной длиной n

Comment: @Gigabait посмотри финальную версию, то что нужно или нет? Код разбит на смысловые части, чтобы понятней тебе было.